# Avoiding the use of for loops

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I would like to get some help with how to avoid using for loops. I've seen several similar questions but have not been able to figure something specific to my needs. Currently I use loops and it is very bulky and messy. Below is the structure of the data and what I would like to achieve:

I have to index data from **1080** timepoints which come from variable `mean_data` which is a **1080x1** double. Some of the timepoints belong to specific task conditions and specific events that I am interested in. There are 3 conditions (**cond1, cond2, cond3**) and 4 task events (**event1, event2, event3, event4**). This information comes from variable `params`. Specially column 8 of `params` has the condition information (1, 2, 3 mean cond1, cond2, con3, respectively). The event information can be obtained from column 11 in `params`. Below is what I can do with loops:

```
for c=1:size(params,1)
        if params(c,8)==1
            cond1_event1(end+1,1)=mean([data(params(c,11)+3,1),data(params(c,11)+4,1)]);
            cond1_event2(end+1,1)=mean([data(params(c,11)+6,1),data(params(c,11)+7,1)]);
            cond1_event3(end+1,1)=mean([data(params(c,11)+8,1),data(params(c,11)+9,1)]);
            cond1_event4(end+1,1)=mean([data(params(c,11)+10,1),data(params(c,11)+11,1)]);

        elseif params(c,8)==2
            cond2_event1(end+1,1)=mean([data(params(c,11)+3,1),data(params(c,11)+4+1,1)]);
            etc.

        elseif params(c,8)==3
            cond3_event1(end+1,1)=mean([data(params(c,11)+3,1),data(params(c,11)+4,1)]);
            etc.
        end
    end
```

The loops make it clear but it's just too long. Does anyone have any suggestions how to make this a bit more elegant?  The output should yield **12 variables (3 condition x 4 events)**. Each variable is a `nx1 double`. Thank you.

Comment: How much is the execution time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use logical indexing, then use vertical concatenation.

```
idx = params(c, 8) == 1;
cond1_event1 = [cond1_event1; mean(...)];
```

Then repeat for the other conditions, or use a loop(1:3).